# Protege reasoner's equivalent conclusion

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I have found this issue while developing an ontology. I am making ontology over the basic family relations.

I have a main class called `Person`, which contain sub-classes like `Son`, `Daughter`, `Wife` etc.
Along with this I defined object properties like `isGrandsonOf` and `isGranddaughterOf` to show the relation grandparent-grandchild.

Issue is that whenever I start the reasoner, it tell me that `isGranddaughter` and `isGrandson` is exactly the same. It vary is such aspects as: Domain (female subclasses are disjoint with male one) and Disjoints, as the screens shows. Could someone please explain this to me? I am not sure how to declare these two object properties being unequal. I am using either FaCT++ or Pellet reasoner.

Both first and second image shows how object property, in inferred as equal, meanwhile I do not want `isGrandsonOf` and `isGranddaughterOf` to be the same object property. They both refer to people with different sex:

- [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQoMU.png)
- [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZjTB.png)

Comment: "as the screen shows" - except you don't show the screen. Please edit your question to show the actual details of what your ontology looks like, what error you're getting, etc. Without those details, this is impossible to answer.

Comment: 1. making `isGrandSonOf` as the inverse of both `isGrandfatherOf` and `isGrandmotherOf` looks odd - does this really make sense? Please make sure about the characteristics of the `inverseOf` relation in OWL - this will lead to undesired inferences for sure in your case. 2.  if I'm not wrong, it looks like a bug as `isGrandSonOf` it's shown as beeing equivalent to `isGrandDaughterOf` while at the same time beeing declared as disjoint with each other. This should lead to an unsatisfiable property. 3. You can click on the `?` next to the equivalence axiom and see the explanation for the inference

Comment: Thus, please show as the explanation, i.e. add a screenshot here.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments. 1. Well I did it on purpose to be honest. How else I could define that both male and female instances can have both grandfather and grandmother? 2. This seems like a bug to me to. I will try to check some different possibilities later today as well. Maybe something will come up to my mind. 3. The thing is that whenever I click this button next to this axios, the window that pop up is empty, there is no explanation available at all. I will try as well with older Protege versions. Maybe that will help.

Comment: How about splitting role and gender? With isGrandParent, you won't get the complications of having the property tell the gender. Then you can have Grandma as Female and exists isGrandParent.

Comment: Well, this might be an idea.. Anyway I have checked with older Protege versions and seems, that 'isGrandson' and 'isGranddaughter' are exactly the same object properties, despite fact that both of them are disjoint.